# How would I find similar lines in two CSV files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

Here is my code but it takes forever for huge files:

```
require 'rubygems'
require "faster_csv"

fname1 =ARGV[0]
fname2 =ARGV[1]
if ARGV.size!=2
    puts "Display common lines in the two files \n Usage : ruby user_in_both_files.rb <file1> <file2> "
    exit 0
end

puts "loading the CSV files ..."
file1=FasterCSV.read(fname1, :headers => :first_row)
file2=FasterCSV.read(fname2, :headers => :first_row)
puts "CSV files loaded"

#puts file2[219808].to_s.strip.gsub(/\s+/,'')

lineN1=0
lineN2=0
# count how many common lines
similarLines=0
file1.each do |line1|
    lineN1=lineN1+1
    #compare line 1 to all line from file 2
    lineN2=0
    file2.each do |line2|
        puts "file1:l#{lineN1}|file2:l#{lineN2}"
        lineN2=lineN2+1
        if ( line1.to_s.strip.gsub(/\s+/,'') == line2.to_s.strip.gsub(/\s+/,'') ) 
            puts "file1:l#{line1}|file2:l#{line2}->#{line1}\n"
            similarLines=similarLines+1
        end
    end 
end
puts "#{similarLines} similar lines."
```

Comment: How long is forever?  How huge is huge?

Comment: about 300000  lines for each csv file and it takes more than 30m to finish

Comment: How much RAM is on your host? How long are the lines being loaded? What OS is the code running on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby has set operations available with arrays:

```
a_ary = [1,2,3]
b_ary = [3,4,5]
a_ary & b_ary # => 3
```

So, from that you should try:

```
puts "loading the CSV files ..."
file1 = FasterCSV.read(fname1, :headers => :first_row)
file2 = FasterCSV.read(fname2, :headers => :first_row)
puts "CSV files loaded"

common_lines = file1 & file2
puts common_lines.size
```

If you need to preprocess the arrays, do it as you load them:

```
file1 = FasterCSV.read(fname1, :headers => :first_row).map{ |l| l.to_s.strip.gsub(/\s+/, '') }
file2 = FasterCSV.read(fname2, :headers => :first_row).map{ |l| l.to_s.strip.gsub(/\s+/, '') }
```

Comment: i followed your instructions but it is very slow i mean really slow

Comment: i finally tackled the problem by splitting the large array into N smaller array.(its like using buffers), with this process i reached the speed of light. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're `gsub`ing File2 every time you loop through File1.  I'd do that first, and then just compare the results of that.

**Edit** Something like this (untested)

```
file1lines = []
file1.each do |line1|
  file1lines = line1.strip.gsub(/\s+/, '')
end

# Do the same for `file2lines`

file1lines.each do |line1|     
  lineN1=lineN1+1     
  #compare line 1 to all line from file 2     
  lineN2=0     
  file2lines.each do |line2|     
    puts "file1:l#{lineN1}|file2:l#{lineN2}"     
    lineN2=lineN2+1     
    if ( line1 == line2 )      
        puts "file1:l#{line1}|file2:l#{line2}->#{line1}\n"     
        similarLines=similarLines+1     
    end     
  end      
end
```

I'd also get rid of all the `puts`es in the loops unless you really need them.  If the files are huge, that's probably slowing it down a noticeable amount.

Comment: thank you so much, it am cutting like half of the time, but it still takes like 20m

Comment: You can try getting rid of lineN1 and lineN2.  You're incrementing them then, from what I can see, not doing anything with them.  That probably won't improve your speed too much.

Comment: Another question: Why are you doing the strip, then the GSub?  I'd think gsubbing for \s should take care of what the strip is doing.  Removing the strip will help a bit.